# PyQt: How do I change the customContextMenu trigger?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'd like to change how a custom contextMenu is triggered on a widget, but I haven't found a solution.  I'm adding a contextMenu to a QListWidget in a standard way:

```
self.shotsList = QtGui.QListWidget()
self.shotsList.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.shotsList.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.shotsPopUp)
```

A user has requested the menu appear on right mouse press (as opposed to mouse release), then they can select a menu item, which is triggered on release (marking menu style).

Is this possible?

Comment: What platform(s) is this on? The behaviour you describe is the default on linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
#customContextMenu trigger
#This is the example code for customContextMenu trigger
#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.


import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class Window (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName('listWidget')

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 220, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName('pushButton')
        self.pushButton.setText('Add')

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName ('verticalLayout')        

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)


        #Right click menu
        self.listWidget.setContextMenuPolicy (QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)        
        self.listWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect (self.rightClickFunction)                     

        self.action            = QtGui.QAction (self)
        self.action.setObjectName('action')        
        self.action.setText ('Open')

        self.action1            = QtGui.QAction (self)
        self.action1.setObjectName('action1')        
        self.action1.setText ('Test')  

        self.customMenu         = QtGui.QMenu('Menu', self.listWidget)       
        self.customMenu.addAction (self.action)
        self.customMenu.addAction (self.action1)

        #self.customMenu.addAction (QtGui.QIcon(''), 'Open', (self.oepnFunction))          
        #self.customMenu.addAction (QtGui.QIcon(''), 'Test', (self.testFunction))      

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect (self.addItem)
        self.action.triggered.connect (self.oepnFunction)
        self.action1.triggered.connect (self.testFunction)

        #void changed ()
        #void hovered ()
        #void toggled (bool)
        #void triggered (bool = 0)


    def addItem (self) :
        count   = int (self.listWidget.count ())         
        self.listWidget.addItem (str(count+1) + '_')


    def rightClickFunction (self, event) :
        index = self.listWidget.indexAt (event)
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        item = self.listWidget.indexAt(event)
        self.customMenu.popup (QtGui.QCursor.pos())       


    def oepnFunction (self) :
        print 'hai............open'

    def testFunction (self) :
        print 'hai............test'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```